# Twitter bootstrap showing first n characters of string

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a screen which has some text adjacent to each other.If these text are long then overlapping happens between them.

So I am looking for some api in bootstrap or jquery which shows only first n characters of string and when we do mouse over complete string appears.

Comment: Can you define what you expect to see when you say "when we do mouse over complete string appears"? Do you mean as a tooltip (easier), or should the text widen in-place to show the full text (harder)?

Comment: yes...... in tooltip form

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick plugin I wrote for this purpose. It use title attribute (tooltip) along with shortening string. e.g.:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

with Script:

```
$.fn.shortText = function(str,length){
    var item = $(this);    
    var toset = str; 
    if(str.length > length) 
        toset = str.substring(0,length) +'..';
    item.text(toset).attr('title',str);
}
$('#first').shortText('Some very long string',10);
$('#second').shortText('Some very long string',99);
```

Just the plugin:

```
$.fn.shortText = function(str,length){
    var item = $(this);    
    var toset = str; 
    if(str.length > length) 
        toset = str.substring(0,length) +'..';
    item.text(toset).attr('title',str);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/wysc6/